# C# and IOS RSA public key encryption

Tags: c#, ios, encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption

Ok so basically i have a WCF service which provides the IOS application with a public key, i want to encrypt data with the public key and send it to the WCF service.

On the C# wcf service i use `RSACryptoServiceProvider` and at the moment i export to a CspBlob byte array. but i guess i would need to use xml export.

So thats fine, i need to somehow create a `SecKeyRef` to encrypt the data on IOS.

Iv tried looking for a working solution but all i can find is [this library](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/downloads_ios.asp) and it cost a lot of money just to encrypt some data. I also found [this](https://github.com/StCredZero/SCZ-BasicEncodingRules-iOS) but i cant get it to work.
And there is a failed attempt over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14615894/2027232) using this.

Can someone help me encrypt data with RSA public key encryption on IOS. It needs to be able to decrypt on C#.

Comment: Why can't you use SSL?

Comment: We are using ssl, but the company im working for wants this encryption as well as ssl. We are working with very sensitive data. and it seems appropriate to encrypt the data.

Comment: So you're encrypting this "very sensitive" data, and yet the $300 for the library you mention is "a lot of money"? Given that SSL is essentially trusted with billions of dollars each day by securing  connections used for online banking, stock trading, etc. the fact that you cannot justify a $300 expenditure (whether it's actually required or not) suggests this data really isn't all that valuable after all, and hence, SSL is entirely adequate.

Comment: We have already spend a lot of money on the project and this can be done without paying. SSL only protect the data through the network.

Comment: Check out my answer for similar case

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17955406/importing-an-objective-c-rsa-public-key-into-c-sharp-rsacryptoserviceprovider/28841819#28841819