# iOS: Where shall I keep RSA public key in my application?

Tags: ios, iphone, encryption

**What I am doing?**
- I am building an application where users signIn with Google in order to use my App.
- Since Server has no idea is request is coming from a device, a trust mechanism is needed in order to handshake.
- I created pair (private key, public key) using `RSA` algorithm. The intent is that public key will be staying on device(with application).
- Once user signs in, application encrypts user information with public key and sends to server using `REST API`. The server validates and inturn returns a token, that client(iPhone app) can reuse to communicate further with server.

**Question**
- Since I am new to developing `iOS`(or any mobile) application, I wanted to know where this public key will be stored in my `iOS` application

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best practices for iOS applications security](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9448632/best-practices-for-ios-applications-security)

Comment: Generating a key pair on the device and then sending the **private** key to the server is completely against the principles of the asymmetric crypto.

Comment: pair would be generated one time by me and hardcode public key on server and private key on app. Does that sounds incorrect?

Comment: might be helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10222524/rsa-implementations-in-objective-c