# IPhone xcode RSA decryption from file

Tags: iphone, xcode, file, encryption, rsa

Using the apple built in Security framework and common crypto libraries I do not want to randomly generate RSA keys but I want to hardcode the file containing my special private key into the following function:

Code below was found here but I want to modify it to accomplish the above: [Iphone - How to encrypt NSData with public key and decrypt with private key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10072124/iphone-how-to-encrypt-nsdata-with-private-key-and-decrypt-with-public-key/10072378#10072378)

```
- (void)decryptWithPrivateKey:(uint8_t *)cipherBuffer plainBuffer:(uint8_t *)plainBuffer 
{ 
    OSStatus status = noErr; 

size_t cipherBufferSize = strlen((char *)cipherBuffer); 

NSLog(@"decryptWithPrivateKey: length of buffer: %lu", BUFFER_SIZE); 
NSLog(@"decryptWithPrivateKey: length of input: %lu", cipherBufferSize); 

// DECRYPTION 
size_t plainBufferSize = BUFFER_SIZE; 

//  Error handling 
status = SecKeyDecrypt([self getPrivateKeyRef], 
                       PADDING, 
                       &cipherBuffer[0], 
                       cipherBufferSize, 
                       &plainBuffer[0], 
                       &plainBufferSize 
                       ); 
NSLog(@"decryption result code: %ld (size: %lu)", status, plainBufferSize); 
NSLog(@"FINAL decrypted text: %s", plainBuffer); 

}
```

Is it possible to do it with this function or do I have to rewrite the whole function to accomidate for my own private key use?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to read this from a file by inputing the file path and importing the files to the project.