# How to Encrypt mp3 Files in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, encryption, avplayer

I have an app that downloads MP3 files from our web server and momentarily stores them in an NSData object. This object is then written to a .mp3 file stored to the /Library/Cache folder in the app's sandbox.

When it is time to play the file, I load it into an AVPlayerItem like so:

```
    NSString *filePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]
                          stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.mp3", trackID]];

    NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:filePath];
    self.trackPlayerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithURL:fileURL];
```

I think proceed to load this item into an AVPlayer and play it.

So my main question is: How do I encrypt these mp3 files while they're stored on the disk to ensure they can't just be plucked from the file system by anyone with a Jailbroken device?

I've already looked on Stack Overflow but couldn't find anything that helped.

Hope someone can help me out. Thanks

Comment: You don't even need to jailbreak for the files to be accessible. Check out http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer for just one app that allows this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10072124/iphone-how-to-encrypt-nsdata-with-private-key-and-decrypt-with-public-key) on adding RSA encryption/decryption to `NSData`.

Comment: Thanks for the link. How would I go about encrypting the .MP3 file like that? Encrypt the downloaded NSData, save the NSData to the disk for the cache and only decrypt and re-save as MP3 when needed?

Comment: @KiranPanesar your mp3 file is just an `NSFile` so when creating it with `- (BOOL)createFileAtPath:(NSString *)path contents:(NSData *)contents attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes`, use the encrypted `NSData` for the contents. When playing loading the file, use `[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:mp3FileName];` to retrieve the data and decrypt it before playing.

Comment: Got the encryption & decryption working – thanks. But because I'm loading the track into an AVPlayerItem, have you got an idea on how I would load an NSData object into AVPlayerItem?

Comment: @KiranPanesar post a new question, it could be useful for other people.

Comment: Good idea. Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11780455/how-to-load-nsdata-into-an-avplayeritem