# How to Load NSData into an AVPlayerItem?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsdata, avplayer

This is a follow-on question from my post about [How to Encrypt mp3 Files in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11764177/how-to-encrypt-mp3-files-in-ios).

How would I go about loading a track into an AVPlayerItem using NSData rather than a file path/URL?

Thanks

Comment: Write it to file then load that file

Comment: +1 to @Dustin.  The AVPlayerItem class really doesn't leave you much alternative.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
[/*name of NSData*/ writeToFile:/*save file path*/ atomically: YES];
NSURL *filepath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:/*save file path*/];
AVPlayerItem *player = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:filepath];
```

Untested, but should work.

Comment: +1 for taking the time to provide an example.  I was too lazy :)

Comment: Thanks for the example. I'm really hoping there's another way to do it because re-saving the MP3 in unencrypted form (even if it is only momentarily) presents a bit of a security issue, I think?

Comment: It depends how secure your mp3 has to be... You can delete the file right after you're done if it's such a big deal.

Comment: @Dustin Yeah, that's what I'm going to do. I'm sure it'll be more than secure enough, but it's not perfect. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: For those who stumble upon this, AVAudioPlayer's `initWithData` method may be of help

Answer (score 1):

Updating [Dustin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11780663/840428) for Swift 5:

```
var audioData: Data // some audio data
var fileURL: URL // some local path, probably appending NSTemporaryDirectory() 
try! audioData.write(to: fileURL)
let item = AVPlayerItem(url: fileURL)
```