# How encode with public key and decode with private?

Tags: ios, objective-c, rsa

I still have no simple method to do something like:

```
NSString *stringForEncrypt = @"Some string";
NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData *encryptedData = [data encryptWithPublicKey:public_key];
//....
NSData *decryptedData = [encryptedData decryptWithPrivateKey:private_key];
NSString *decryptedString = [NSString alloc] initWithData:decryptedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

BOOL isItWorks = [stringForEncrypt isEqualToString:decryptedString];
```

Can I implement it using only Security.framework? Anybody?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Iphone - How to encrypt NSData with private key and decrypt with public key?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10072124/iphone-how-to-encrypt-nsdata-with-private-key-and-decrypt-with-public-key)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [NSData+AESCrypt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10072124/iphone-how-to-encrypt-nsdata-with-private-key-and-decrypt-with-public-key/10073040#10073040) and here is [my solution](https://github.com/kvint/ios-encryption).

Comment: How does this work? It looks like you are using different keys for encryption and decryption with a symmetric key algorithm.

Comment: Whoops, sorry. Seems you are right. I'm dumb... I must change the algorithm.