# Encrypt or protect cached files in the application documents, to be opened only by the application

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios5, nscache

I'm using `EGOCache` to cache `NSData` and then reread the `NSData` into `NSDictionary`, so when I checked the `iPhone Simulator` file to see if the data is protected!! I found that I can open it easily!. So what I am asking about, is there any way to protect or encrypt these (sensitive data)??

Comment: The solution described here is probably what you want.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10072124/iphone-how-to-encrypt-nsdata-with-public-key-and-decrypt-with-private-key

Comment: You can include `<CommonCrypto/CommonCryptor.h>` in your class, you can find helpful functions in it

Comment: If this will be your first release to the app store make sure you are aware of [cryptography export laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Export_of_cryptography_in_the_United_States)

Comment: thanks all, but can EGOCache do that?? I saw some people use EGOCashe to cache data and I tried to open it but I coudn't!!