# How to convert UIImage to cipher text?

Tags: ios, encryption, uiimage

I need to convert `UIImage` to cipher text and send it to server and again need to convert back the cipher text to `UIImage` and make sure its the correct one.

Can some one please let me know how to do this? I have no idea. Any documentation provided is also great.

Thanks...

Comment: Why can't you just connect to the server using **https** (SSL), which is already encrypted?

Answer (score 0):

You will first need to convert UIImage to NSData

[convert UIImage to NSData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476929/convert-uiimage-to-nsdata)

Then you encrypt that NSData

[Iphone - How to encrypt NSData with public key and decrypt with private key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10072124/iphone-how-to-encrypt-nsdata-with-public-key-and-decrypt-with-private-key)

Answer (score 0):

Here is [an article](http://highaltitudehacks.com/2013/09/26/ios-dev-encrypted-images-and-saving-them-in-app-sandbox/) by *Prateek Gianchandani* which is about [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor) - a library for encrypting images, which uses AES256. It's much more simple and convinient to use it instead of manual `NSData` encryption.